# AWS - ECS run a task show this error Reasons : ["RESOURCE:PORTS"]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

When I try run a task in my service using ECS a errors message is displayed

Run tasks failed
Reasons : ["RESOURCE:PORTS"]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can I release the port once it's being used by one task? What is the other option if I din't have any other port to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the scheduler cannot assign your task to an instance because it requires a fixed port that is already taken. The simplest solution is to choose another port number in the specification of your task.

You could also allow the scheduler to allocate the port dynamically, but in this case you would probably want to define a service attached to a load balancer in order to expose it to the outside world.

Comment: What parameters do you use to run the task?

Comment: More details about your service, currently running tasks, and number of instances in the cluster would be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had one instance running and I was ssh'ed into it and got this error.

I logged out and I was able to run the task.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to update a service which load a task. It helps me.